# Java getResource return null mac

Tags: java

I am very new to StackOverflow and I've done my best to fix this problem before posting this question here. I'm faced with the problem of getResource() returning null. I have a hunch that this is because I'm on a mac and the pathing is different here than on a PC (where this code seems to work fine). This is the code:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    static String imgpath = "/theimage.png";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(imgpath);
        System.out.println(SampleClass.class.getResource(imgpath));
        try
        {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SampleClass.class.getResource(imgpath));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

`src`, `res` and `bin` are all in the same directory and `theimage.png` is inside of `res`.

`System.out.println(SampleClass.class.getResource("imgpath"));` gives me null.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a massive difference between `getResource("imgpath")` and `getResource(imgpath)` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I must have made a mistake when changing the variable names. In the original code there are no "". When removing them the problem still persists.

Comment: With the path `"/theimage.png"` you are using, the file need to be directly in the src, i.e. `src/theimage.png`. The `/` brings the search to the root of the classpath, which is (before build), the src

Comment: I moved theimage.png from res to src. Still having the same error. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: It _should_ work. It is the correct way. You can still have it in the res if you want, but make sure the res is in the src `src/res/theimage.png` and use `getResource("/res/theimage.png");`. This, given everything else is correct, always works. So check everyhing else

Comment: That's very odd, perhaps I have misunderstood you? src, bin and res are now in the same folder and I have moved theimage.png from res to src.

Comment: Forget about `bin`. You don't need to worry about that. That is for the IDE's view. Just worry about the `src`, that is _your_ view. When the IDE runs your program, it should copy all the files in the `src` into the `bin` and compile all your .java files to .class files and put them in the bin also.

Comment: So from the IDE view, you should be basically seeing `Project/src/res/theimage.png` and using `getResource("/res/theimage.png");`. Clean and build your project if you need to. Also try creating a new project and trying.

Comment: I am trying to be as specific as possible to avoid misunderstanding, sorry if the text becomes too long. I put theimage.png in res and put res in src. Changed imgpath = "/res/theimage.png" still returning null. This is in a new project.

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I am using Eclipse.

Comment: OK create a new Java Project. Create a `res` package in the `src`. Add the image the `res`. Create a package for your class. Just create one simple class, and call the code we've been talking about. Then run the application. If that works, then check your original project to see what you may be doing differently. If it doesn't work, I don't know what to tell you. This always works for me

Comment: See [images and example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097/2587435)

Comment: Thank you for at least trying, if I ever figure it out i'll try to post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get nullpointer exception because there is no image named imgpath in that folder

```
public class SampleClass
{
    static String imgpath = "/theimage.png";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(imgpath);
        System.out.println(SampleClass.class.getResource(imgpath));
        try
        {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SampleClass.class.getResource(imgpath));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Made an error when changing the variable name, the problem is still there when removing the "". I'll edit it.

Comment: what "" that you removed?

Comment: I removed the quotation marks around imgpath, made an error when changing some variables.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my mac using spring boot :

the file is located on **properties/report/example.jasper**

when the path was : "report/example.jasper" i got nullPointerException

So i changed to : **"./report/example.jasper"** and It works fine without any bug.

```
  InputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        inStream = ExportController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
        final JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inStream);
        jasperReport.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL);
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);
    } catch (final JRException jre) {
        throw new TechnicalException("Error when export jasper");
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            inStream.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on Mac. Here how I now get files from resources. For example, I have a common Maven project with **resource** folder in **src/main**. In resource folder I have a file "**test.txt**".

To get a path to the file:

```
public class Utils {
    public static String getFilePathInResources() {
        URL url = Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt");
        return url.getPath();
    }
}
```

Here the filename is hardcored just for clearity, of course, really it is a parameter in the method.

If set a filename as "**/test.txt**" with "/" - this will give **null**.

```
URL url = Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/test.txt"); // url == null
```