# Problems with images when compiled

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar, embedded-resource

I have been all over the internet trying to work out how to get an image icon displayed after compiling into a runnable jar. I discovered this problem way too late, I ran my program many times before in eclipse and every thing has worked, now 6 months later with project finished, I compiled my program with eclipse and no audio or images work. Reading on the net, it says about the location of images folder should be inside jar, but mine doesnt get put there?

I have played around with the images folder moving it inside the source folder, but it didn't work. I have a feeling that it might be something to do with the path of the resource...ebut thats only guessing.

I have built a simple program that has the same results... works when ran in eclipse, but not when compiled. Could somebody show me an example by modifying my code below. Thanks in advance.

SOURCE CODE:

```
package ImageIcon;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui {

public static JLabel c;

public Gui(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBounds(0, 0, 120, 200);
    p.setBackground(Color.black);
    p.setLayout(null);

    JPanel bg = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    bg.setBounds(50, 50, 15, 15);
    bg.setBackground(Color.white);

    ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("images/success.jpg");
    c = new JLabel(a);

    f.setSize(100, 200);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    f.add(p);
    p.add(bg);
    bg.add(c);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Gui();
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("images/success.jpg"); use getResouses

Comment: after reading on stakOFlow, I coded ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/success.jpg")); and it didnt work, why is this?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet yeah i saw that finally .and yeah it's not work

Comment: Instead of `"images/success.jpg"` use `"/images/success.jpg"`

Comment: @AndrewThompson - just tried adding the "/", but that now doesnt show the image when run in eclipse or when compiled.

Comment: @getlost  `..new ImageIcon("images/success.jpg");` That **won't** work for an embedded resource because the JVM is trying to load a file of that name.

Comment: @peeskillet - this is defo a duplicate question. I just havent quite grasped what others have tried to describe. However, ive not seen thispage you linked to and it seems to explain in some depth. Ima go and gibe it a read a moment. Thanks so far guys.

Comment: *"just tried adding the "/","* I only just noticed the `images` directory does not seem to be in a place such that the content is included in the Jar.  Have you checked the content of the Jar?

Comment: BTW `p.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: The images folder doesnt get compiled into the jar at all

Comment: And just to be clear, I meant using it like this.. `..new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/success.jpg"));`

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I tried all variations including what you meant, but no, thats not worked either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current directory setup, the `images` dir won't even get built into the jar. Try to extract it and you will most likely see that it's not in there.

You can tell by the fact that it doesn't have the little package logo in the folder, as seen here with `resources`

[image]

The only default directory built into the classpath (/jar) is the `src`. We need to either put the `resources` into the `src`

[image]

or configure the build path to include the files that are in the `resources`. Once we do that, we will see the little package icon inside the folder icon. That's how we know the files are on the build path

[image]

---

### **CODE we would use:**

- **First Image:** Can't, it won't work (this your current predicament)
- **Second Image:**

  ```
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
           getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow.png"));
  ```
- **Third Image:**

  ```
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
           getClass().getResource("/stackoverflow.png"));
  ```

To configure the build path to use the third option, follow the instructions in [**Example 2 in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097/2587435)

Comment: Brilliant guide, I noticed that this seems to be quite a common issue, hopefully this will clear it up for many. I took the second option as it seems much simpler to achieve, but I will also have a blast at option3 anyhow. It seems logical, but what you describe above will also apply to all resources, is this correct? Thanks anyway, works a charm.

Comment: Pretty much. Any resource you need to access from the classpath

Answer (score 2):

As from your screenshot, the image exists in a folder called "images". Put it in a folder inside your classpath: src/images/success.jpg and call:

```
ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/success.jpg"));
```

Comment: this hasnt worked either, but thanks for your effort.

Comment: Both answers are right. Though here a slight mistake, it should be `getResource("/images/success.jpg")` if place in `src/images`. Another point: the file names must be **case-sensitive** (zip format), where Windows file system (eclipse) is more relient.