# Inserting icons in downloadable jar application

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jar

I am a novice programmer trying to create a jar file that people can download and demonstrates a...JRPG-ish upgrade system I have. As a little visual pop, I want the central button to display a little icon as an extra visual pop. While it works fine in Eclipse, when I export it to a JAR file the icon is no longer displaying (though the rest of the program works as intended.

[image: Eclipse vs JAR]

I have managed to make Eclipse import the files I want into the JAR file, as seen below.

[image: Overview of project]

This is the code I currently have to display them in Eclipse

```
imgDin = new ImageIcon("icons\Mark_of_Din.png");
imgNayru = new ImageIcon("icons\Mark_of_Nayru.png");
imgFarore = new ImageIcon("icons\Mark_of_Farore.png");
```

How can I modify this code to display them inside the JAR file?

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127/java-swing-displaying-images-from-within-a-jar

Answer (score 3):

You should be using

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Mark_of_Din.png"));
```

That little package icon in the `icons` folder icon, means the files in the `icons` folder will be at the root of the classpath. `getClass()` gets the calling class, and `getResource()` locates a resource relative to the class. The `/` brings the search to the root.

You can extract the jar and you will see the `icons` folder is not there.

- See [Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26341881/2587435)

---

> "While it works fine in Eclipse.."

That's because when you pass a String to the `ImageIcon` constructor, it is looking for a file on the file system, relative to the working directory. In Eclipse (and most IDEs), the default working directory is the project root, and that's where your `icons` folder is.

Comment: your answer is reasonable that is why I have deleted my answer, thanks dear for correction, I am voting you up :)