# Eclipse Project Wont Work After changing to executable jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

i have been having a problem for a while where when i export my eclipse project into an executable jar file it wont run correctly. I think the resources folder is the source of this problem but i'm not sure, because all that happens whenever i run it is the JFrame pops up. for some reason i cant take screenshots because my computer is a piece of crap, but I've shared what i know. thank you, all help is much appreciated!

UPDATE:
this has been tagged as duplicate, but i have tried their methods and it wouldn't work. i need instructions specific for my situation.[This is the link to the picture of my file explorer took a little while back when i had the same problem, because i cant take the picture now it is not up to date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh5Om.png)

Comment: just for clarification, it DOES run correctly inside of eclipse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java project working on Eclipse but not working when exported to runnable jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452508/java-project-working-on-eclipse-but-not-working-when-exported-to-runnable-jar-fi)