# How to make a jar runnable in order to save images

Tags: java

I have a problem:
I put my images in my project folder, for example, E:\All Work IT\Java All\JavaWork\TestingDB and when I use this line of code to use the images

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("start.png");
```

It works perfectly!
But when I want to make a Runnable jar file (Export -> select Runnabable jar file) and open the specific jar, the images don't appear on the buttons, menu, and so on.

Where do I need to put my images to solve this problem, and with what code?
Thanks.

Comment: Put the images within the context of jar (so they embedded) then use Class#getResource to load them. How you include the images in your jar will depend on how you are building the jar

Comment: Please can you confirm which, if any IDE your using.

Answer (score 2):

new ImageIcon(file) specifies a local file which won't work inside a JAR.. Try changing the line to use a the class loader.

```
 new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/start.png"));
```

If you're in a static context

```
 new ImageIcon(Foo.class.getResource("/start.png"));
```

I'm unsure of your project structure or IDE, if any, so I'm unable to make any recommendations on where images should go. Just make sure the images are included in the JAR export and end up at the top level, or structure matching your getResource() call

Comment: Read the question - the images don't exist within the jar

Comment: I assumed E:\All Work IT\Java All\JavaWork\TestingDB was the IDE project, and that the generate runnable JAR would have picked them up... especially as the code new ImageIcon("start.png") managed to find them, implying they were in the current directory...

Comment: The images are found, because they are with in the relative execution context of the program, that doesn't mean they located with the context if the project. So, if you're very lucky, you've answered half the question. Assume makes a "ass" out of "u" and "me" - no offense intended, it's something one of mentors says to me all time. Don't assume anything, either cover all the possibilities (as much as possible) or ask questions for clarification

Comment: Surely it seems unlikely that a novice developer has reconfigured their launch config (assuming eclipse) to change the current working directory to some other location on disk. It would default to the project directory... Also question states " I put my images in my project folder". By default Create Runnable JAR in eclipse mops up everything in project directory...

Comment: Again, you're assuming a context where no evidence exists.  What if they are using NotePad++ and are hand building the project?  There's nothing to suggest anything about how the OP is building there project...*"By default Create Runnable JAR in eclipse mops up everything in project directory"* - From my experience with all the other questions related to Eclipse and missing resources (and not using Eclipse myself) that doesn't seem to be correct - but that's based on the questions people ask about Eclipse and missing resource and not experience with Eclipse itself.

Comment: Don't forget, despite what might be going on your world, not everybody uses Eclipse or Maven and some people (as crazy as it might sound) don't use IDE's at all.

Comment: Question used terminology "create runnable jar" which has since been updated to "file...  export...  create runnable jar". Which kind of implies ide unless notepad has that now. My axperience of eclipse feature of same name is that top level files do get swept up.

Comment: Well, you're two example structures won't work for my working environment. You're still assuming context...

Comment: I've removed examples in case they were misleading

Answer (score 1):

One if the simplest ways would be to include the images within the jar file itself, this reduces the number of resources you'll need to deploy; much easier to deploy a single jar then a jar file and a bunch if images

It also reduces the possible issues with execution context and having to calculate the relative paths

Who you achieve this will depend on how you are building the jar, for instance in Netbeans and Eclipse, you can copy the images into the `src` directory. In maven, you'd need to include the images in the `resources` directory

This will change the way you need to use to load the images or resources

You will need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` depending in your needs, for example

```
ImageIcon img = getClass().getResource("/start.png");
```

Remember, you will need to use the full path to the image from the context of the `src` directory

This means if you place the `resources` within the `images` directory under the `src` directory, then you will need to use `/images/start.png` for example

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion!
Like I said to Adam, I use Eclipse IDE. and that path that I put in my question, it was my project folder created in Eclipse. 
I try to create a folder named resources in src folder, and in that new folder I put my all images. After that I use this line of code
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/start.png");
And I have the same behavior.
The jar file I created in this way:
Right click on project, select Runnable jar and then click on finish after I select Extract required libraries into generated JAR
I am sorry because I don't know

Comment: The resulting `jar` file is just a zip file.  Try unzipping it and seeing if the images are within the `resources` directory

Comment: I extract it, and I don't have the folder images.. why happening that? 
I mention that I have a package in my project folder named : testing.db.stef and when I extract the zip I have the meta-inf, org and testing folder.

Comment: And you put the `resources` file in the `src` folder?

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images) of some help

Comment: I put my folder-images in src folder and like I said, after I unzip I have just testing folder.. I try to put the images-folder in testing folder, and after I unzip, this folder with images, doesn't exist....

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. MadProgrammer. Your link helped me. 
I use the first example and it work perfectly even after I make a runnable jar file. 
Thanks again!