# Why does getResource return null

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, assets, getresource

I'm trying to access a file in my project. But getResource method returns null.

This is how my project looks like:
[image]

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("assets/xxx.png"); //returns null
```

And how project folder in eclipse workspace looks like:

[image]

Why? I want to access files in my assets folder?

**Edit**
I created a jar file and this is content of the jar:

[image]

**Solved**

First of all, I've a lot of image files so I want to organize all them in a folder. I put the assets folder in src directory and finally I was able to access the files.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("assets/xxx.png");
```

[image]

Comment: You can't access the assert folder unless otherwise you have bundled it in your jar. Can you extract a jar and show the content of so that we can help you.

Comment: Is asset folder defined as source folder?

Comment: @AlexR yes, defined as source folder

Comment: @Eranda I did it.. I edited my post, can you take a look?

Comment: `assets/` should not be in the path. It's an outside (not in the src) folder in the build path, which just means its contents are put into the root, without the directory. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097/2587435)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of ways to add a resource to the jar file, you can put it in src, add as a resource if you use maven, ant etc... If you able to bundle whole directory then you should be able to use your original piece of code.
With the current structure you can use following piece of code.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/xxx.png").
```

Comment: If I simply add all files to bin directory I can access. But there are many files in my project and I want to organize them in a directory. So I want to put all files in a folder and access them from this directory.

Comment: Put the whole asserts directory in src (source) folder. Eclipse will bundle that for you.

Comment: @Eranda - Your code seems to get a relative path. What is it relative to and how can I find out the root ?

Answer (score 2):

For someone struggling as me. For Maven just run `mvn clean install`.
After that `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource()` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `/` prefixing.

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/xxx.png")`

Comment: as per your `jar` structure i can see that image file in root. i updated my answer try once again. Thanks

Comment: try using getResourceAsStream, and change your class to take `Inputstream` instead of `File`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using the the class loader of the current class? Something like `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/xxx.png")` should be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, it should work.

`YOUR_CLASS_HERE.class.getClass().getResource( "/xxx.png" );`

e.g.
`Signin.class.getClass().getResource( "/xxx.png" );`

Answer (score 0):

Either Approach will work. its just Filepath issue.

- Your Jar Structure shows no "asset" Folder
  xxx.png file is directly in Jar File.

Try to remove "assets" from below line of code.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("assets/xxx.png"); //returns null
```

- Also, if you want to use "assets"  folder in ur classpath, please ensure that your jar contains "assets" folder.