# Path for retrieving resources with ClassLoader

Tags: java, eclipse, image, embedded-resource

Basically, I want to include my main `JFrame`'s icon in the JAR file, so not to need to load it from an external location.

To achieve this, I searched about Java's resource system.
What I have done with Eclipse:

1. I have created a new folder named "res":

   [image]
2. I have copied the files inside it using Windows' explorer:

   [image]
3. I have made that folder a source folder:

   [image]
4. I have written this code:

   ```
   URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/res/icona20.ico");
   ```

But `url` is `null`.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the `/res` in the path

Comment: When you add a folder to the build path, it is not part of the path, instead all the contents are put at the root of the classpath

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet But I want the "src" folder to hold .java files only. I want resources to be in a separate folder. How could I achieve this? Am I going against the language recommendations?

Comment: Look at the second example in the link. And no there is nothing wrong with put the files a different folder. If it's in the build path, all the files from the folder (excluding the folder) get built into the jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned you seem to have added `res` as source folder, so it is a root, not to name, like `src`.

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icona20.ico");
```

Class loaders use an absolute (case-sensitive) path, without explicit leading slash `/...`.

Relative paths with an obligatory leading slash for absolute paths:

```
URL url = Xyz.class.getResource("/icona20.ico");
```

And you might prefer `.png` instead of `.ico` as the latter format is not standard in Java SE.

(About common practices.) The build tool `maven` uses as nice standard the following source folders:

```
/src/main/java/
/src/main/resources/
/src/test/java/
/src/test/resources/
```

Your usage of `res` is reminiscent of MS Visual Studio ;).

Comment: Yes, I have a [tag:vb.net] background. There's no static method like `ClassLoader.getResource(String)`.

Comment: You are right; should have been `getSystemResource`. Corrected. I think Andres corrected too, and his answer then should be adequate & first.

Comment: As a side note, you cannot use .ico images for `JFrame`'s icons; you can use the .png format instead. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

The classloader will get the resources starting from each source folder you added to the classpath. Therefore, the URL should be the following:

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icona20.ico");
```