# Java: Jarring a .png to your jar file?

Tags: java, embedded-resource

```
public Frame(String title) {
    setTitle(title);
     try{
          Clip crit = AudioSystem.getClip();
            AudioInputStream inputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("k.wav"));
            crit.open(inputStream1);
            crit.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
     }        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Frame.class.getClassLoader().getResource("img/lel.png"))));
    setVisible(true);
    setBounds(600,600,1024,833);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add the lel.png and k.wav to be inside of the JAR file to make my program work?

Comment: Just trying to jar it, and it didn't work.

Comment: What tools are you using?

Comment: What do you mean tools?

Comment: There are different ways to create a jar file.  I'm trying to figure out what you're using so that I can tell you what steps you need to take to add a PNG file.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse to jar it.

Comment: Your eclipse project probably has a `src` folder.  Try putting your PNG file at `src/img/lel.png`, then create the JAR again.

Comment: I'm getting a NPE at that line if I do that

Comment: Open up the JAR file with 7-Zip or WinZip or something (they're just zip files) and verify that the file is actually at that location.

Comment: They're not in there when I extract it from the Jar file

Comment: Okay, well I expected it to work by putting the PNG into the resource folder (src), but apparently I'm wrong or missing something.  You can manually add it to the WAR file if you need to.  I don't have Eclipse installed on my current machine, but I'd verify the actual steps for you if I could.  Sorry about that!  I hope that's helpful.

Comment: More [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

If you generate your jar file and put the resource files and the jar file in a folder structure like below, you can use relative paths.

`myjar.jar
data/
---k.wav
img/
---lel.png`

Ex:

```
try {//we need to catch UnsupportedAudioFileException
    AudioInputStream inputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("data/k.wav")); 
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
```