# How can I package a resource file into a runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried this in many ways, and followed several online instructions, such as this - 
[Eclipse exported Runnable JAR not showing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images)
But so far, no success.

I have a very simple program that reads a text file (test.txt) and prints out its contents to standard output. I am using Eclipse. Here is what I have done-

- I put the text file into a folder called 'resources'
- I right-clicked the resources folder, selected "Build path" and hit "Use as resource folder"
- In my code, I tried two ways of addressing the file - (a) as "/test.txt" and (b) as "resources/test.txt. The latter method works when I run the program within Eclipse. However, neither method works when I export the project as a runnable jar file. The resource folder fails to be included in the jar file.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Addendum:
Here is the code.

```
public class FileIOTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/test.txt")));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    br.close(); 
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

}

Comment: Show actual code of how you load the file.

Comment: public class FileIOTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String line;
  try {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/test.txt")));
   while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
   }
   
  br.close(); 
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

 }

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse exported Runnable JAR not showing images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images)

Comment: By "Show actual code" they mean put it in the question, so it's formatted and clear.

Comment: @khuderm, if you read my post you will see that I have checked the very post that you say is a duplicate of mine. I have already checked that one and followed the directions, to no avail.

Comment: @BearArmatis, I have added code to my post. I was unable to edit out the unformatted code that I initially posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not access a resource in a Jar file through a `FileReader` because it is not a file on the file system. Java does have a mechanism for accessing resources in your classpath (including in Jars): [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-). You can use it with your default classloader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
                                   .getResourceAsStream("test.txt")));
```

Note that `getResourceAsStream` returns `null` instead of throwing an exception, so you may want to get the stream first, check if for `null`, then either throw an exception or process it.

You will want to give the full path within the jar as your path.

Comment: It's how you access stuff that you would normally get from a ClassLoader. Basically, anything that comes from within your application distribution (i.e., is on your application's classpath) should be read this way. The `null` return value reflects this: things loaded this way are much more reliable than things from the file system.

Answer (score 2):

Files work differently from resources. If you want a resource, then you should not be trying to use any of the `File(Xxx)` variants, which will look on the file system.

The link you provided, used `Class.getResource` which returns a URL, but there is also `Class.getResourceAsStream` which returns an `InputStream`, which you can wrap in an `InputStreamReader`. For example

```
InputStream is = FileIOTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/text.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create jar without eclipse. For example, if I have a `Demo` class in package `src` (directory is the same), and the resource file (named `testing.txt`) is in `resources` directory. I add a `Manifest.txt` file @ the root of the directory :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: src.Demo
```

The `Demo` class looks like :

```
package src;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Demo.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/testing.txt"))))
        {

            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `testing.txt` file is like :

```
hello world
How are you?
```

Compile `Demo.java` to obtain `Demo.class`

```
javac src/Demo.java
```

Create `jar`

```
jar cfm myJar.jar Manifest.txt src/* resources/*
```

And run it

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

In eclipse, just add the resources folder at the classpath (be sure it is in the jar), and read it as a classpath resource (the `getResourceAsStream` method)