# Alerts in JavaFX – Icons don’t show up after exporting jar

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8, alert

I’ve been trying to develop an application using Alerts, but after exporting the jar, the icon that should be displayed in the dialog, is gone:

[image: confirmation without icon]

When I start from Eclipse, the icon is shown:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
The code:

```
public class Main extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.show();
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** When starting from the command line, the following error is printed:

com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager getCachedImage

WARNING: Error loading image: rsrc:dialog-confirm.png

I can’t figure out, why the image is (probably) missing.

Comment: You also have to export the images that you use in your application, for example by using a separate package below your src-folder. You also can manipulate your buildpath. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images

Comment: Exporting standard JavaFX alert images with the application jar file shouldn't be necessary Supahupe.  The standard JavaFX alert images ship with the Java runtime environment (Oracle JRE 8u40+).

Comment: "after exporting the jar" <= How do you export the jar?  Do you use e(fx)clipse tooling?  Do you (mistakenly) try to include jfxrt.jar as a bundled resource with your jar distribution?  Any idea where the "rsrc:" string (which I've never seen before) in your error message comes from?  Do you have some kind of OSGi application or weird, custom class-loading solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to export via File → Export → Java → Runnable JAR file. As jewelsea already wrote, the way of exporting it is important. [Oracles documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html) says, I should use Ant Tasks. After reproducing it with Eclipse, as described [here](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/), it worked.

I wasn't able to find a good explanation why this approach is necessary though.