# Error to export external images to generate a Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, executable-jar

I'm trying to export my project into a Jar file, but problems goes that when i export it, shows me a error message: `"JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.  Exported with compile warnings: SemilleroProject/src/AppFixed.java`

`SemilleroProject` is the folder where i stored all images that the application use.
How can i export that folder in order to generate a jar with the images resources too? `SemilleroProject` folder is in the root directory.

Comment: How are you exporting the project to a JAR file? using Eclipse? If yes then this link should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images

Comment: yes, using elipse

Comment: A warning is not an error.

Comment: The AppFixed.java assumably has compiler warnings. Fix these!