# Background music using java JLayer plays in eclipse and runnable jar but doesn't play when a client downloads and runs it

Tags: java, audio, jar, lwjgl

I currently have an LWJGL game with background music. When I run my game in Eclipse everything seems fine. The music also works when I export it as a runnable jar. However, when I put my game on a web server and a client downloads and runs it, the music doesn't play. I initially had the following:

```
try{
    File file = new File ("/Users/me/Documents/workspace/LWJGL-T/src/file.mp3");
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream (file);
    BufferedInputStream bufferStream = new BufferedInputStream (fileStream);
    Player player = new Player (bufferStream);
    player.play();
}
catch (Exception e){
   System.err.println (e.toString());
}
```

After some research, I found out that FileInputStream shouldn't be used with mp3 files so I implemented the following, which didn't work at all.

```
    InputStream fileStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Users/me/Documents/workspace/LWJGL-T/src/file.mp3");
```

Any help would be appreciated; thank you!

Comment: Why do you think the user would have `/Users/me/Documents/workspace/LWJGL-T/src/file.mp3` on the PC?  If you want the make the file available at runtime to the user, you should embed the file within the Jar and then you can make use of `getResourceAsStream`

Comment: Will take a chance... It looks like the file is on your local box.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments below your original post, the file you're trying to access is only stored on your computer. You'll have to include the file in your jar (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636097) for setting that up) and after that, the line below should work:

```
InputStream fileStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.mp3");
```